# Preprocessor Shorthand for const * const

Tags: c++, constants, c-preprocessor, shorthand

I have a large code and many of my functions accept arguments of the type 
`<typename> const * const <varname>` or `<typename> const * const * const <varname>`

Would it be horribly abusive to define a preprocessor shorthand like
`_CsC` or `_CsCsC`

e.g.
`#define _CsC const * const` and `#define _CsCsC const * const * const`

Where the `C` stands for `const` and the `s` stands for `*` and the `_` is to get your attention that this is a `#define`d shorthand.

I realize that the initial reaction might be "Huh what?" but once you've read more than a few lines of the code, seems like you'd adjust to it and it'd improve readability by allowing you to see the type/varname faster...

Initial tests compile and the double pointers are much more readable, it seems to me.

Comment: "Would it be horribly abusive to define a preprocessor shorthand like..."  Yes.  But, do use typedefs to shorten long type names.

Comment: @ James can you give me an example of what you mean??  To me the two seem similar...

Comment: I'm mostly appalled by the underscore-capital name. Otherwise, knock yourself out.

Comment: I'm just appalled by the fact that your code does this often enough for you to feel this is necessary.

Comment: Note that names starting with an underscore and followed by another underscore or a capital letter are reserved for the implementation to use.  On those grounds alone, the names `_CsC` or `_CsCsC` should be avoided.  I wouldn't like to read the code, but I've seen worse abuses of the preprocessor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a template:

```
template <typename T> using CsCsC = const * const * const T;
```

Usage:

```
CsCsC<Foo> x = /* ... */;
```

Comment: Hmm, I like that... maybe that would be less abusive. :)

Comment: Ah, I get an `expected unqualified-id before 'using'` when I try to compile your line there.  Is this c++0x ?

Comment: @JasonR.Mick: It's C++11. As Jack Nicholson would have said, "is there any other kind?" :-)

Answer (score 6):

It would be horrible and abusive, yes. Use a `typedef` instead.

Comment: Why do you think it's abusive?  

I ask because I meant it in the sense that it's unexpected, but seeing a `char_CsC` and getting a `const * const char` seems abusive in an unexpected sense too. :)

Answer (score 0):

To explain Luchian's answer:

if you use

```
typedef int * IntPtr;
typedef int ** IntPtrPtr;
```

and you write

```
const IntPtr x;  
const IntPtrPtr y;
```

then it is equal to

```
const int * const x;
const int * const * const y;
```

Comment: But then the struct or inline instances become longer and less readable (as you're shortening the const name, but lengthening the non-const name)...

Comment: @JasonR.Mick: If I understand your argument, then if it's the number of characters you're aiming for, then use `typedef const IntPtr CsCsC;`

Comment: Nevermind, my apologies, my brain short-circuited there for a second, forgetting you could use the standard int ** everywhere else... in a way that seems less consistent/ubiquitous though than my original solution, abusive as it may have been... The typedef route is an interesting idea there.